# Filling Job detail values in the JDBC datastore

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm  learning Quartz and I've gone through the tutorials. I used the RAM JOB store. Now I want to move it to jdbc job store. I've created database and configured it. But the scheduler has not started. What is the values that I've to populate it with the database.

Comment: For a bit of clarification - I presume this is from a standalone application rather than Spring /framework integrated webapp?

Comment: Yeah it is an standalone application

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to populate the database. It is highly recommended to NOT write directly to quartz tables: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/best-practices.

Just configure the scheduler programmatically by adding triggers and job details as described in example: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/examples/Example1.